# MotoG kernel compile from sources issues

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-ndk, android-source, android-kernel

**Goal** I am new to kernel compile thing. My goal is to build the kernel from source for motoG.

**Work Done**

Until now I have downloaded following modules.

- [motoG kernel source](https://github.com/MotorolaMobilityLLC/kernel-msm)
- [Android r5c NDK](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r5c-linux-x86.tar.bz2)

Also following [tutorial](http://ohheyitslou.blogspot.hk/2011/09/ohheyitslou-custom-android-kernel-guide.html) I have performed all steps without any error until "final make" command.

**Error**

However when I try to run make to compile kernel I receive following error:

```
drivers/gpu/msm/adreno_snapshot.c: In function 'snapshot_ib':
drivers/gpu/msm/adreno_snapshot.c:638: sorry, unimplemented: inlining failed in call to 'parse_ib': recursive inlining
drivers/gpu/msm/adreno_snapshot.c:598: sorry, unimplemented: called from here
```

Can anybody please suggest me which point I am doing wrong. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Forward declaration for `static inline` function looks unusual. See, e.g., that discussion: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/2262303. Also, as far as I understand, function's definition in that case should omit `static` keyword, as in the case with non-inline forward declaration. `static inline int parse_ib(...); ` ... `inline int parse_ib(...) {...}`.

Comment: I removed inline and error is removed .. not a proper solution though.